# Implement an iOS Calendar with Multiple selection enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar, tapku

I'm trying to implement a calendar which enables multiple selections. So far, I've been using Tapku an I'm able to implement my datasource proper but I can't seem to get the multiple selection going. Would anyone happen to have any suggestions how I could go about doing so?

I understand that Tapku wasn't exactly build to support multiple selections (struggling so much to modify it to allow such)

Thanks so much!!